# How to use reflect and interface{} to implement polymorphism of methods with argument in Golang?

Tags: go

I am porting some code from C++ to golang. I did some research on OOP and polymorphism in golang, all suggest using interface and embedding to implement polymorphism. I have a sample code written as follows

```
type Worker interface {
    Show()
    Inc()
}

type WorkerA struct {
    x int
    Worker // embed all methods in interface
}

type WorkerB struct {
    WorkerA // embed WorkerA to have all methods
}

func (a *WorkerA) Inc() {
    a.x++
}

func (a WorkerA) Show() {
    fmt.Println("A:", a.x)
}

func (b WorkerB) Show() {
    fmt.Println("B:", b.x)
}

func main() {
    list := make([]Worker, 10)
    for n:=0; n<len(list); n++ {
        if n%2==0 {
            list[n] = &WorkerA{}
        } else {
            list[n] = &WorkerB{WorkerA{}}
        }
    }
    list[0].Inc()
    list[1].Inc()
    list[1].Inc()
    list[2].Inc()
    list[2].Inc()
    list[2].Inc()
    list[0].Show()
    list[1].Show()
    list[2].Show()
```

With the help of the interface array, I could call the corresponding `Show` method for `WorkerA` and `WorkerB`. Now I would like to add a third method call` Add`which add the`x``` between two Workers

```
func (a *WorkerA) Add(b WorkerA) {
    a.x += b.x
}
```

I find that calling the following will cause an error before `list` is holding interface not the struct

```
list[0].Add(list[2])
```

I look up some idea online, see that `reflect` may help to solve the problem, here is what I write

```
func callMethodParam(p interface{}, q interface{}) {
    o := reflect.ValueOf(p)
    m := reflect.ValueOf(q)
    args:=[]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(m)}
    o.MethodByName("Add").Call(args)
}

callMethodParam(list[0], list[2])
```

But this does not seem to work either. Any idea how to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question sounds like an XY problem but here luckily we know X, do we?

Also the code `list[0].Add(list[2])` can't work as it appears in your example because `list` is declared as a slice of `Worker` and `Worker` doesn't have a `Add` method.

But let's pretend it does. Given that the implementation of `Add(b WorkerA)` requires accessing a `WorkerA`'s `x` field, you could change the signature to accept an interface that provides `x`, and have `WorkerA` implement that interface:

```
type XProvider interface {
    X() int
}

func (a *WorkerA) X() int {
    return a.x
}

func (a *WorkerA) Add(b XProvider) {
    a.x += b.X()
}
```

Then before calling `a.Add` you use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to make sure that (the type contained in) a particular instance of `Worker` also implements `XProvider`:

```
if xp, ok := list[2].(XProvider); ok {
    list[0].Add(xp)
}
```

Here's an updated [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bfjUofGVg18)